# How to track ecommerce data of users who get redirected from the old site to the new site?

Tags: google-analytics

I am switching from my old domain to my new domain. The new site is up and running and I already set up 301 redirects in the old site. 
I'm wondering if it is possible to track the ecommerce data of users who get redirected from the old site in Google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add utm_* parameters to your redirection url. Inside of 301 redirection page you could place for example:

http://www.newwebsite.com/?utm_campaign=Redirect

You will see all the redirected users coming from source traffic of type "Campaign" with name "Redirect". You are able than to use it as a filter in e-commerce reports.